# Forwarding owncloud from PI to router

Tags: raspbian, networking, php, port-forwarding, owncloud

## Aim:

Have an owncloud on a raspberry, available from public network e.g. from the IP of my router rather than from the IP of my Raspberry.

## Background info

```
root@DietPi:~# uname -a
Linux DietPi 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@DietPi:~# cat /etc/issue.net
Raspbian GNU/Linux 9
root@DietPi:~# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.19.66-v7+ (dom@buildbot) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611)) #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019
```

## Progress:

I am following mainly this guide here:
https://www.avoiderrors.com/set-up-raspberry-pi-owncloud-server/

Currently Everything is working fine with local settings, ( e.g. on 192.168.0.103 ).

On my router(tp-link) I have set the following virtual server:

```
Service Port - 80
Internal Port - 80
IP Address -    192.168.0.xxx
Protocol - TCP
```

### Final change

as said in the guide, I have edited the config.php file like so:

```
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    1 => '<real ip>',
  ),
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://<real ip>/owncloud',
```

### After this change

http:///owncloud is not working from a computer being hooked to the same router.

Error is: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

#### Attempts:

1. Tried restarting PI
2. Tried restarting router, editing config.php again
3. Tried connecting from a different source
4. Tried playing with config.php

Meanwhile, the local owncloud was still working perfectly.

Found something interesting in the tp-link admin page (192.168.0.1), the ISP had set an option in Network->WAN->WAN Connection Type: -> PPPoE/Russia PPPoE with user and password

I haven't tried other routers on other ISPs.

## Question:

Can you advise how should I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: You have tagged your question Raspbian but appear to be using something else.

Comment: The local owncloud was still working perfectly. Do you ask how to troubleshoot your router? Isn't **DietPi** a distribution like **Raspbian**? Are you using DietPi or Raspbian?

Comment: @Ingo DietPi is the proper Distro, which is based on Raspbian